# R rpivotTable add Plotly chart renderers

Tags: javascript, r, plotly, pivottable.js, rpivottable

I want to add  Plotly chart renderers to the `rpivotTable()` function from the
R package [rpivotTable](https://github.com/smartinsightsfromdata/rpivotTable). I followed the instructions given in the [Javascript Pivot Table](https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/wiki/Optional-Extra-Renderers) Wiki to add optional extra renderers. Unfortunatey, following these instructions will lead to the default behaviour. Maybe I assigned the Java code to the wrong arguments.

Here is a small example:

```
library(rpivotTable)
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output){

  output$mypivot = renderRpivotTable({
    rpivotTable(
      Titanic,
      renderers = htmlwidgets::JS("$.extend($.pivotUtilities.renderers,
            $.pivotUtilities.plotly_renderers)"),
      rendererName = "Horizontal Stacked Bar Chart"
    )
  })
}
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(src = "https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js")),
  rpivotTableOutput("mypivot"))
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This isn't possible today but we're working on a new rpivotTable release where the plotly renderers would be bundled and this type of thing might work (source: I'm the author of PivotTable.js, a contributor to rpivotTable and a Plotly employee :)

Comment: See the GitHub Issue - https://github.com/smartinsightsfromdata/rpivotTable/issues/89 - created to track this